# Retrieving some columns from database with Breeze.js, and still be able to update database

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am new to Breeze.js, but really enjoy it so far. I ran into an issue with updating a database with Breeze.js, when selecting only portion of columns of a model.

When I ran this statement:

```js
$scope.emFac.entityQuery.from('Company');
```

the company entity matches my EF entity, retrieves all columns, creates entityAspect, and all is working fine when updating database:

[image]

However, when I retrieve only portion of corresponding Model's columns, Breeze.js returns anonymous object with specified properties (retrieving data works, but not updating does not), without the entityAspect, which is being used for tracking changes.

Here is the code with select statement:

```js
$scope.emFac.entityQuery.from('Company').select('companyId, displayName');
```

Is there a way to retrieve only some columns of EF Model columns, and still track changes with Breeze.js, needed for database updates?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, Breeze treats the incoming data as plain objects instead of entities when you use `select`.

Your choices are:

1. On the server, Create a `CustomerLite` or similar object, and have a server endpoint that returns those without the need for `select`; OR
2. On the client, get the results from the query and create entities from each object, with status `Unchanged`

Example of #2:

```
var entities = [];
em.executeQuery(customerProjectionQuery).then(queryResult => {
  queryResult.results.forEach(obj => {
    // obj contains values to initialize entity
    var entity = em.createEntity(Customer.prototype.entityType, obj, EntityState.Unchanged);
    entities.push(entity);
  });
})
```

Either way, you will need to ensure that your `saveChanges` endpoint on the server can handle saving the truncated Customer objects without wiping out the other fields.